# Inequality 6 variables

Tags: inequality

Prove the following inequality with a, b, c, x, y, z is positive number:

$$x^2(a+b)+y^2(b+c)+z^2(c+a)\geq 2(xy+yz+zx)\sqrt{\frac{ab+bc+ca}{3}}.$$

I expanded it as follows.

$$x^4(a+b)^2+ y^4(b+c)^2+z^4(a+c)^2 + 2 xy^2zbc + 2 xyz^2ac + 2 x^2yzab \geq 2(xy^2z+x^2zy+xyz^2)(ab+bc+ca)$$

Comment: i have tried Cauchy Schwarz with each pairs but it didnt work :)

Comment: the problem is "Prove the following inequality with a, b, c, x, y, z is positive number:
$$x^2(a+b) + y^2(b+c) + z^2 (a+c) \geq 2(xy+yz+xz) \sqrt{\frac{ab+bc+ca}{3}}$$" and it is equivalent to the above inequality.

Comment: Ok... have you tried to prove the above inequality at all?

Comment: I have tried it. but i cannot solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The hint.

Prove and use the following lemma.

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be non-negative numbers such that $4abc\geq a+b+c+1$. Prove that:
$$ax^2+by^2+cz^2\geq xy+xz+yz$$