# Inequality with 6 variables

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Hello I would like to prove this with $a,b,c,x,y,z$ real numbers :

> $(x^2 +y^2 )(x^2 +z^2 )(y^2 +z^2 )+a^2 b^2 c^2 +a^2 b^2 (x^2 +y^2 )+a^2 c^2 (x^2 +z^2 )+b^2 c^2 (y^2 +z^2 )
> \geq 2abxy(x^2+y^2)+2acxz(x^2+z^2)+ 2bcyz(y^2+z^2)+xyz(abz+acy+bcx)$

My try :

Now we suppose this $a>0$,$b>0$ and $c>0$.

Furthermore we have the following relations:

$abxy\leq ab\sqrt{z^2+y^2}\sqrt{x^2+z^2}$

$acxz\leq ac\sqrt{z^2+y^2}\sqrt{y^2+z^2}$

$bcyz\leq bc\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sqrt{x^2+z^2}$

And
$xyz\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sqrt{x^2+z^2}\sqrt{z^2+y^2}$

So we have the following majorization :

$ 2abxy(x^2+y^2)+2acxz(x^2+z^2)+ 2bcyz(y^2+z^2)+xyz(abz+acy+bcx)\leq 2ab\sqrt{z^2+y^2}\sqrt{x^2+z^2}(x^2+y^2)+2ac\sqrt{z^2+y^2}\sqrt{y^2+z^2}(x^2+z^2)+ 2bc\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sqrt{x^2+z^2}(y^2+z^2)+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sqrt{x^2+z^2}\sqrt{z^2+y^2}(ab\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+ac\sqrt{z^2+x^2}+bc\sqrt{z^2+y^2})$

The initial inequality becomes:

$(x^2 +y^2 )(x^2 +z^2 )(y^2 +z^2 )+a^2 b^2 c^2 +a^2 b^2 (x^2 +y^2 )+a^2 c^2 (x^2 +z^2 )+b^2 c^2 (y^2 +z^2 ) \geq 2ab\sqrt{z^2+y^2}\sqrt{x^2+z^2}(x^2+y^2)$ $+2ac\sqrt{z^2+y^2}\sqrt{y^2+z^2}(x^2+z^2)+ 2bc\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sqrt{x^2+z^2}(y^2+z^2)+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sqrt{x^2+z^2}\sqrt{z^2+y^2}(ab\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+ac\sqrt{z^2+x^2}+bc\sqrt{z^2+y^2})$

If we divide by $(abc)^2$ we get :

$\frac{(x^2 +y^2 )}{c^2}\frac{(x^2 +z^2 )}{b^2}\frac{(y^2 +z^2 )}{a^2}+1+\frac{(x^2 +y^2 )}{c^2}+\frac{(x^2 +z^2 )}{b^2}+\frac{(y^2 +z^2 )}{a^2} \geq 2\frac{\sqrt{z^2+y^2}}{a}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}{b}\frac{(x^2 +y^2 )}{c^2} +2\frac{\sqrt{z^2+y^2}}{a}\frac{\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}{c}\frac{(x^2 +z^2 )}{b^2}+ 2\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{c}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}{b}\frac{(y^2 +z^2 )}{a^2}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sqrt{x^2+z^2}\sqrt{z^2+y^2}}{abc}(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{c}+\frac{\sqrt{z^2+x^2}}{b}+\frac{\sqrt{z^2+y^2}}{a})$

Finally if we make the following substitution :

$\frac{(x^2 +y^2 )}{c^2}=u$

$\frac{(x^2 +z^2 )}{b^2}=v$

$\frac{(y^2 +z^2 )}{a^2}=w$

We find :

$$uvw+1+u+v+w\geq 3\sqrt{uvw}(\sqrt{w}+\sqrt{v}+\sqrt{u})$$

So it works with the condition $uvw=0.2$ ,and maybe for $uvw\leq 0.2$ so it's a partial proof .

My question is :if it's correct could you complete my reasoning ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: there is a link with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1944563/inequality-6-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've hacked out what appears to be a proof of the $a, b, c, x, y, z$
inequality, but it's not enlightening, so it would be interesting to
know the source of the problem.

---

Before presenting my proof, I'm obliged by the terms of the question
to address the OP's strategy of trying to prove the desired
inequality by deducing it from his other conjectured inequality,
involving only the expressions $u, v, w$.

There is nothing wrong with this as a general idea. (At least, I
hope not, because my attempt at a proof below does something quite
similar.) The trouble lies with the particular expressions $u, v, w$
chosen, because, as Michael Rozenberg has pointed out in a comment,
they are not constrained in any way.  *Any* triple of positive
values $u, v, w$ can be obtained by choosing suitable values of
$a, b, c, x, y, z$, for example $x = y = z = 1$, $a = \sqrt{2/u}$,
$b = \sqrt{2/v}$, and $c = \sqrt{2/w}$. In particular, we may get
the values $u = v = w = 1$, which cause the conjectured inequality
in $u, v, w$ to fail, as Michael Rozenberg pointed out in his
answer.

---

We may assume without loss of generality that $a, b, c, x, y, z$
are all non-negative.

(In the general case, if we replace these numbers by their
respective absolute values, the LHS of the claimed inequality is
unaltered in value, and the RHS is either unaltered or increased
in value, because
$$
|xyz(abz + acy + bcx)| \leqslant
|x|\cdot|y|\cdot|z|\cdot
(|a|\cdot|b|\cdot|z| + |a|\cdot|c|\cdot|y| + |b|\cdot|c|\cdot|x|),
$$
and so on.)

If we temporarily write $S = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$, the required
inequality can be rewritten as:
\begin{align*}
& \mathrel{\phantom{=}}
(S - x^2)(S - y^2)(S - z^2) + a^2b^2c^2 + 
b^2c^2(S - x^2) + c^2a^2(S - y^2) + a^2b^2(S - z^2) \\
& \geqslant
2bcyz(S - x^2) + 2cazx(S - y^2) + 2abxy(S - z^2) + 
xyz(bcx + cay + abz).
\end{align*}
This quickly simplifies to:
\begin{align*}
& \mathrel{\phantom{=}}
S(y^2z^2 + z^2x^2 + x^2y^2 + b^2c^2 + c^2a^2 + a^2b^2) -
\phantom{n} \\
& \mathrel{\phantom{=}}
(b^2c^2x^2 + c^2a^2y^2 + a^2b^2z^2) + a^2b^2c^2 - x^2y^2z^2 \\
& \geqslant
2(bcyz + cazx + abxy)S - xyz(bcx + cay + abz),
\end{align*}
which can then be rearranged as:
\begin{align*}
& \mathrel{\phantom{=}}
(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)[(bc - yz)^2 + (ca - zx)^2 + (ab - xy)^2] \\
& \geqslant
x^2bc(bc - yz) + y^2ca(ca - zx) + z^2ab(ab - xy) +
x^2y^2z^2 - a^2b^2c^2.
\end{align*}
To make further progress with this, write:
$$
r = bc - yz, \quad s = ca - zx, \quad t = ab - xy,
$$
and note that:
$$
a^2b^2c^2 = (bc)(ca)(ab) = (r + yz)(s + zx)(t + xy).
$$
We now have to prove:
\begin{align*}
& \mathrel{\phantom{=}}
(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)(r^2 + s^2 + t^2) \\
& \geqslant
rx^2(r + yz) + sy^2(s + zx) + tz^2(t + xy) + 
x^2y^2z^2 - (r + yz)(s + zx)(t + xy) \\
& =
(r^2x^2 +s^2y^2 + t^2z^2) - (styz + trzx + rsxy) - rst.
\end{align*}
An obvious idea now is to apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, thus:
\begin{align*}
& \mathrel{\phantom{=}}
(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)(r^2 + s^2 + t^2) \\
& \geqslant (|r|x + |s|y + |t|z)^2 \\
& = (r^2x^2 +s^2y^2 + t^2z^2) + 
2(|st|yz + |tr|zx + |rs|xy).
\end{align*}
While there is no guarantee that this will help, it does tell us
that it would be sufficient (although it may well not be necessary)
to prove this new inequality:
$$
2(|st|yz + |tr|zx + |rs|xy) + (styz + trzx + rsxy) + rst
\geqslant 0.
$$

With our expressions $r, s, t$, we are in a similar situation to the
OP, with his $u, v, w,$ because we are faced with having to prove a
new inequality that is *not* true for unrestricted values of
$r, s, t,$ if they are considered as independent real
variables. (Take, for example, $x = y = z = 1$, $r = s = t = - 10$.)

Because $|styz + trzx + rsxy| \leqslant |st|yz + |tr|zx + |rs|xy$,
we may as well start by trying to prove the even simpler inequality:
\begin{equation}
\label{ineq:simple}
\tag{$*$}
|st|yz + |tr|zx + |rs|xy \geqslant -rst.
\end{equation}
Fortunately, this does turn out to be true, with the given
definitions of $r, s, t$. (There is probably a quick way to prove
it, but if so, I've missed it, so please excuse the blind slog that
follows!)

Obviously, there is nothing to prove if: (i) any of $r, s, t$ is
zero; or (ii) $r, s, t$ are all positive; or (iii) two of $r, s, t$
are negative and the third is positive.  So, we need only consider
two cases: (iv) $r, s, t$ are all negative; (v) one of $r, s, t$ is
negative and the other two are positive.

In case (iv), dividing \eqref{ineq:simple} through by the strictly
positive quantity $-rst$, we find that what has to be proved is:
$$
\frac{yz}{yz - bc} + \frac{zx}{zx - ca} + \frac{xy}{xy - ab}
\geqslant 1,
$$
which is trivially true, because each of the three terms on the
LHS is individually greater than $1$.

In case (v), by symmetry, we may assume without loss of generality
that $r < 0$, $s > 0$, and $t > 0$. Dividing \eqref{ineq:simple}
through by the strictly positive quantity $-rst$, we find that what
has to be proved in this case is:
$$
\frac{yz}{yz - bc} + \frac{zx}{ca - zx} + \frac{xy}{ab - xy}
\geqslant 1,
$$
and this is also true, because the first term on the LHS is greater
than $1$, and the other two terms on the LHS are both positive.

This proves \eqref{ineq:simple} in all cases; and it has already
been shown that \eqref{ineq:simple} suffices for the truth of
the original inequality in $a, b, c, x, y, z$.

Comment: Thanks for your reasoning , but I have not the time to see if there are wrongs notes in your proof .So I trust in it .

Comment: @FatsWallers You have more faith in my reasoning than I have myself! (Thank you for that - I needed cheering up!) I did my best to check it before posting, but it's entirely possible that someone else in MathSE will still find a fatal flaw. Peer review is a great thing, and it's marvellous that the Internet (and LaTeX, etc.) makes it available even to amateur dabblers like me.

Answer (score 0):

Your last inequality is wrong.

Try $u=v=w=1$.

Thus, it's not correct.

Comment: You don't understand my question ,the question is when the last inequality works .I'm looking for a condition on $u,v,w$ like $uvw=3$ or $u+v+w=1$,on the one hand I was not very clear,sorry.

Comment: @FatsWallers I think I understood your question very well. See please, how you got $u$, $v$ and $w$. There is no any condition on these variables.

Comment: I edit see the new condition  .

Comment: @FatsWallers $uvw$ can be equal to any positive number. If you look for condition for your last inequality then  I can find it, but it will not help for the starting problem. By the way, I think your starting problem is very hard.

Answer (score -1):

Your inequality is equivalent to, with $a$,$b$,$c$,$x$,$y$,$z$ real numbers:

> $(x^2 +y^2 )(x^2 +z^2 )(y^2 +z^2 )+a^2 b^2 c^2 +a^2 b^2 (x^2 +y^2 )+a^2 c^2 (x^2 +z^2 )+b^2 c^2 (y^2 +z^2 )
> \geq 2abxy(x^2+y^2)+2acxz(x^2+z^2)+ 2bcyz(y^2+z^2)+xyz(abz+acy+bcx)$

My try :

Now we suppose this $a>0$,$b>0$ and $c>0$.

Furthermore we have the following relations:

$cbx\leq cb\sqrt{\frac{(x-z)^2+(x+z)^2}{2}}=d$

$abz\leq ab\sqrt{\frac{(z-y)^2+(z+y)^2}{2}}=e$

$yac\leq ac\sqrt{\frac{(x-y)^2+(x+y)^2}{2}}=f$

$abxy\leq ab\frac{\sqrt{(z-y)^2+(z+y)^2}\sqrt{(x-z)^2+(x+z)^2}}{2}=u$

$acxz\leq ac\frac{\sqrt{(z-y)^2+(z+y)^2}\sqrt{(x-y)^2+(x+y)^2}}{2}=v$

$bcyz\leq bc\frac{\sqrt{(x-y)^2+(x+y)^2}\sqrt{(x-z)^2+(x+z)^2}}{2}=w$

And
$xyz\leq \frac{\sqrt{(x-y)^2+(x+y)^2}\sqrt{(x-z)^2+(x+z)^2}\sqrt{(z-y)^2+(z+y)^2}}{2\sqrt{2}}=q$

So we have the following majorization :

$ 2abxy(x^2+y^2)+2acxz(x^2+z^2)+ 2bcyz(y^2+z^2)+xyz(abz+acy+bcx)\leq 2u(x^2+y^2)+2v(x^2+z^2)+ 2w(y^2+z^2)+q(d+e+f)$

The initial inequality becomes:

$\frac{((x-y)^2+(x+y)^2)((x-z)^2+(x+z)^2)((z-y)^2+(z+y)^2)}{8}+a^2 b^2 c^2 +a^2 b^2 \frac{((x-y)^2+(x+y)^2)}{2}+a^2 c^2 \frac{((x-z)^2+(x+z)^2)}{2}+b^2 c^2 \frac{((z-y)^2+(z+y)^2)}{2}\geq2u(x^2+y^2)+2v(x^2+z^2)+ 2w(y^2+z^2)+q(d+e+f)$

If we divide by $(abc)^2$ we get :

$\frac{((x-y)^2+(x+y)^2)((x-z)^2+(x+z)^2)((z-y)^2+(z+y)^2)}{8a^2b^2c^2}+1+ \frac{((x-y)^2+(x+y)^2)}{2c^2}+ \frac{((x-z)^2+(x+z)^2)}{2b^2}+\frac{((z-y)^2+(z+y)^2)}{2a^2}\geq \frac{2u(x^2+y^2)+2v(x^2+z^2)+ 2w(y^2+z^2)+q(d+e+f)}{a^2b^2c^2}$

Finally if we make the following substitution :

$\frac{(x^2 +y^2 )}{c^2}=u'$

$\frac{(x^2 +z^2 )}{b^2}=v'$

$\frac{(y^2 +z^2 )}{a^2}=w'$

We get :

$$\frac{u'v'w'}{8}+1+\frac{u'+v'+w'}{2}\geq 3\frac{\sqrt{u'v'w'}(\sqrt{w'}+\sqrt{v'}+\sqrt{u'})}{4}$$ wich is true for $u'v'w'\leq 1$

Comment: The constraint $u'v'w' \leq 1$ cannot be imposed, because for example by taking $x = y = z = 1$ and $a = b = c = 1/\sqrt{2}$ we can get $u' = v' = w' = 4$, which causes the new inequality to fail, just like the old one.