# Nice and new triangle inequality

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality

Hello it's related to this (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2460733/inequality-with-6-variables)) :

With $a$,$b$,$c$,$x$,$y$,$z$ real numbers and $a\geq 0$,$b\geq 0$,$c\geq 0$ we have:

> $(x^2 +y^2 )(x^2 +z^2 )(y^2 +z^2 )+a^2 b^2 c^2 +a^2 b^2 (x^2 +y^2 )+a^2 c^2 (x^2 +z^2 )+b^2 c^2 (y^2 +z^2 )\geq 2abxy(x^2+y^2)+2acxz(x^2+z^2)+ 2bcyz(y^2+z^2)+xyz(abz+acy+bcx)$

I have proved the case where $(x^2+y^2)(z^2+x^2)(y^2+z^2)\leq a^2b^2c^2 $

Now I'm interesting by the case $(x^2+y^2)(z^2+x^2)(y^2+z^2)\geq a^2b^2c^2 $

If we put the following substitution :

$x^2=\frac{w+v-u}{2}\geq 0$

$y^2=\frac{-v+w+u}{2}\geq 0$

$z^2=\frac{v-w+u}{2}\geq 0$

And

$u=a^2$

$v=b^2$

$w=c^2$

With this conditions we are in a triangle of sides $u,v,w$ .We name it $PQR$

we get :

$$5uvw\geq \sum_{cyc}\sqrt{uv(u-v+w)(v-u+w)w^2}+\sqrt{\frac{(u+v-w)(u-v+w)(v-u+w)}{8}}[\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{uv\frac{(u+v-w)}{2}}]$$

Now we multiply by $\frac{u+v+w}{2}$ we obtain :

$$\frac{u+v+w}{2}5uvw\geq \frac{u+v+w}{2}\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{uv(u-v+w)(v-u+w)w^2}+S[\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{uv\frac{(u+v+w)(u+v-w)}{4}}]$$

Where S denotes the perimeter of $PQR$,then we divide by $uvw$ to get :

$$5\frac{u+v+w}{2}\geq \frac{u+v+w}{2}\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{(u-v+w)(v-u+w)}{uv}}+\frac{S}{\sqrt{uvw}}[\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{(u+v+w)(u+v-w)}{4w}}]$$

We can rewrite this like this (divide by S) :

$$\frac{u+v+w}{2}\frac{5}{S}\geq \sqrt{\frac{u+v+w}{2}}\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{8}{uv(v+u-w)}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{uvw}}[\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{(u+v+w)(u+v-w)}{4w}}]$$

Or :

$$\frac{u+v+w}{2}\frac{5}{S}\geq \sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{4(u+v+w)}{uv(v+u-w)}}+[\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{w}\sqrt{\frac{(u+v+w)(u+v-w)}{4uv}}]$$

Finally we get :

$$\frac{u+v+w}{2}\sqrt{\frac{uvw}{u+v+w}}\frac{5}{S}\geq \sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{4w}{(v+u-w)}}+\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{(u+v-w)}{4w}}$$

After that I can't continue .

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2460733/inequality-with-6-variables

Comment: Not a duplicate ... $a,b,c$ are non negative this time ... my bad :-)

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit In fact there would have been no loss of generality in requiring all of $a, b, c, x, y, z$ to be non-negative in the other question also, but I'm too confused to say whether this makes the questions duplicates of one another or not! (What confuses me is that in both questions, the same interesting and challenging inequality is proposed, yet the questions appear only to ask about two specific strategies for attacking it.)